# Mysql - dynamic SQL not allowed in trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

I want to create a trigger with dynamic SQL where I get a column name from a variable. Here is my simplified mysql schema:

```
CREATE TABLE products (id int);
INSERT INTO products VALUES (1),(2);

CREATE TABLE attribute_values 
(product_id int, `key` varchar(100), value varchar(100));
INSERT INTO attribute_values VALUES
( 1, 'title', 'Orange'),
( 1, 'code', 'O125'),      
( 2, 'title', 'Pizza');


CREATE TABLE product_attributes 
SELECT  products.id,
        MAX(CASE WHEN attribute_values.key = 'title' THEN attribute_values.value END) title,
        MAX(CASE WHEN attribute_values.key = 'code' THEN attribute_values.value END) code
FROM    products JOIN attribute_values ON products.id = attribute_values.product_id
GROUP   BY products.id;


# trigger
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE attribute_values_after_insert(IN product_id INT, IN column_name VARCHAR(100), IN val VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT concat('UPDATE product_attributes SET product_attributes.', column_name, '=', val, ' WHERE id=', product_id) INTO @sql;

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

    SET @sql = NULL;
END//
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER attribute_values_insert_trigger AFTER INSERT ON attribute_values FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    CALL attribute_values_after_insert(NEW.product_id, NEW.key, NEW.value);
END
DELIMITER ;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/674fd/1

i.e:

table products:

```
+-------------+
| id          |
+-------------+
| 1           |
| 2           |
+-------------+
```

table attribute_values:

```
+-------------+----------+-----------+
| product_id  | key      | value     |
+-------------+----------+-----------+
| 1           | title    | Orange    |
| 1           | code     | O125      |
| 2           | title    | Pizza     |
+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

table product_attributes:

```
+-------------+----------+-----------+
| id          | title    | code      |
+-------------+----------+-----------+
| 1           | Orange   | 0125      |
| 2           | Pizza    |           |
+-------------+----------+-----------+
```

In the trigger I want to update table product_attributes after inserting to table attribute_values.

When I execute query:

```
INSERT INTO attribute_values VALUES (2, 'code', '0126');
```

I get error:

> DDL and DML statements are not allowed in the query panel for MySQL;
>   only SELECT statements are allowed. Put DDL and DML in the schema
>   panel.

Is there a solution for this in mysql?

Thanks for any efforts :)

Comment: I could be missing something but why are you doing this this way? the code you posted n the end still assumes that there is static number of attributes assigned to the product (2 attributes that are title and code). If so: Why not simply LEFT JOIN products  twice  on  attribute_values on product_id and static key value when querying database? You would not need: the triger nor to maintain the view type table (product_attributes), you would not need product_attributes at all (therefore no risk of having dirty or not up to date data).

Comment: No, I don't have a solution. I can only say that the db design is not good. *Either* you know the attributes you are working with, then you make them columns, like `title` and `code` in `product_attributes`, *or* you want to be oblivious to what attributes you are dealing with, then make them generic like in `attribute_values`. But you are using *both* methods on the *same* attributes. You should not do that. Decide for one way or the other. This can be a mix, say `title` and `code` are columns, and others (`brand`, `color`) are not. But never make *one* field *both* a column and generic.

Comment: I tried to simplify the schema as much as I could.

Comment: @rgasiore In my real situation I have dynamic amount of columns.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: In the environment I work in they use approach with attribute_values table. I need to improve speed for some queries which is why I decided to create table product_attributes.

Comment: The documentation says [D.1 Restrictions on Stored Programs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/stored-program-restrictions.html#stored-routines-trigger-restrictions): `SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).`. However, the error message that you show is actually a limitation of [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) not MySQL.

Answer (score -2):

**MySQL in function and trigger not support dynamic insert**
but procedure can support dynamic insert.

so you can make changes in procedure
and make procedure in attribute_values table insert query.

`INSERT INTO attribute_values VALUES(product_id,column_name,val);`

and after you will be just call procedure

`CALL attribute_values_after_insert(2,'code',132);`

```
DELIMITER //
drop procedure if exists attribute_values_after_insert //
CREATE PROCEDURE attribute_values_after_insert(IN product_id INT, IN 
column_name VARCHAR(100), IN val VARCHAR(100))
BEGIN
SET @sql = NULL;

INSERT INTO attribute_values VALUES(product_id,column_name,val);

SELECT concat('UPDATE product_attributes SET product_attributes.', column_name, '=', val, ' WHERE id=', product_id) INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

SET @sql = NULL;
END//
DELIMITER ;

DELIMITER //
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to write SQL commands in all caps, it is *not* acceptable to write normal sentences in all caps, it’s equivalent to shouting. Please never do that. Thanks.

Comment: while calling store procedure from trigger it is throwing the same error