# dynamically build mysql insert statement within trigger

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

i'm trying to create a trigger within my schedule table that will automatically dump the new info into the hourmap table. the issue that i'm having is that within the hourmap table, the employee names are the column headers. this means that i have to dynamically build the column header so that the input hours are placed in the appropriate column. below is the script that im currently trying to get to work but i keep running into issues. either mysql workbench will just stop working and shut down, or when i hit apply, everything appears to run successfully, however, the trigger is never actually created.

schedule table looks like this:

```
------------------------------
id|project_id|employee_id|hours|
--|----------|-----------|-----|
1 | 11       | 22        |8    |
--------------------------------
```

hourmap table looks like this:

```
----------------------------------------
id|ProjectID |ScheduleID |sam|jon|smith|
--|----------|-----------|---|---|-----|
----------------------------------------
```

the employee table looks like this;

```
------------
id|Employee|
--|--------|
1 |sam     |
2 |jon     |
22|smith   |
------------
```

my trigger statement looks like this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `projectscheduler`.`schedule_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `schedule` FOR EACH ROW
SET @EMPNAME=(SELECT Employee FROM employees WHERE id = NEW.employee_id);
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO hourmap (ProjectID, ScheduleID, @EMPNAME)
    VALUES (NEW.project_id, NEW.id, NEW.hours);
END
```

here is my attempt at a stored procedure, however, still no luck.

```
USE `projectscheduler`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `projectscheduler`.`schedule_AFTER_INSERT` AFTER INSERT ON `schedule` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET @sql = NULL;
    SELECT CONCAT('SELECT Emoloyee FROM employees WHERE id = NEW.id') INTO @sql;
    SET @sql = CONCAT('INSERT INTO hourmap (ProjectID, ScheduleID, `',@sql,'`) VALUES(NEW.project_id, NEW.id, NEW.hours)');
    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

ERROR 1336: Dynamic SQL is not allowed in stored function or trigger
```

Comment: Looks as bad DB design. Are you sure to change your `hourmap` table structure each time new employee will be added? What about you need to change employee name? I advice to change your DB structure for normalize it

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev i hear what your saying and i agree. the only reason i have it structured like this is because im plugging this data into a gantt chart and the only way it will ingest the data is if its in a JSON object (columName: value). within the gantt chart, the employee name is a column name. the only other way i can think to do it is to have a pivot table.

Comment: Unfortunately you can not use dynamic SQL statements in triggers and functions. You can write stored procedure and find the ability to call it from code or by schedule https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31202072/mysql-dynamic-sql-not-allowed-in-trigger